# How to interpret the active record count metric from a kafka connect source task?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a kafka connect source task connector (jdbc postgres connector) and I can view the `kafka_connect_source_task_source_record_active_count_avg` metric from this connector. I note that the graph looks like this:

[image]

So we see occasional steps of 100 records. If I change the metric from `_avg` to `max` indeed the steps are of size 100.

I am unsure how to interpret this information, though. Does this mean that right now (end of the chart) there are over 1100 records that have not been committed to kafka, and they've been that way for weeks? I'm wondering why this value doesn't decrease. The connector is on a very active database, so it wouldn't surprise me if it's always "behind" (is that the right word for it?). But I'd like to know if it's at least always working through the back of the messages, or if it's "accumulating" certain messages that are never being committed to kafka for one reason or another, and if this number reflects these "stuck" messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> source-record-active-count

> :The most recent number of records that have been produced by this task but not yet completely written to Kafka.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-196%3A+Add+metrics+to+Kafka+Connect+framework#KIP196:AddmetricstoKafkaConnectframework-SourceTaskMetrics

You could also plot the offsets of the topic you're producing to to see if they follow the same steps of increase

The alternative would be to use Debezium rather than the JDBC source

Comment: I would like to know if the ~1000 messages that have not been written have been the *same* messages for the past 2 weeks, or if there's just a rolling backlog. It's an issue if there are 1000 old stuck messages, but it's fine if there's just always a backlog, and if kafka works through them. Is there a way to check that? Will plotting offsets show me this info?

Comment: Not sure you'd be able to get that information without something like a heap dump of the connector process